# How Can I Force New Office Documents to Have An AD RMS Policy Applied By Default?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, microsoft-office-2010

I would like to create a GPO or use some other mechanism to force all Office documents created in our enterprise to have a default AD RMS policy, unless the user manually assigns one to the document.

I can't seem to find any documentation to that end, so any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen this link?  It looks like what you're asking for, but I'm not sure on account of you saying you couldn't find any documentation...  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8197.rms-templates-managed-by-group-policy-admintemplatepath.aspx

Comment: That refers to specifying the path of where the various templates are located.  I've got that covered through group policy.  I would like to enforce the protection of a file on creation or save, if a specific protection has not been specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any other solution, so I wrote a custom add-in that applies a policy if one does not exist on any opened or saved documents.

Comment: Would you be willing to post the code for that add-in at all? I think that would be very useful for others having the same problem.

Comment: Let me guess it happens to use PowerShell?

Comment: MDMarra - It's pretty basic, but I will likely blog it this weekend.

Comment: Jacob - No, it doesn't. ;)  It's C#.

Comment: kindly share the add-in code. I really need it on my project. Thank you share with me on : hagetdoe@yahoo.com

Comment: Sorry @Francis, that was two jobs ago and I no longer have that code.